# Place Icon on left of Paragraph

Tags: html, css, css-position

I need to place a paragraph on the right of an icon [JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/mdmoura/ojky56ec/13/):

```
  <i class="material-icons">check_circle_outline</i>
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam nec fermentum urna, at convallis turpis. Aliquam luctus mauris arcu, eu sodales mauris sagittis at.
  </p>
```

With the following CSS:

```
i {
  font-size: 36px!important;
  display: inline-block;
}

p {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

They don't appear side by side ...

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you put the `<i>` tag inside your `<p>` tag?

Comment: I don't want any line of paragraph to be under the icon ... Would the <I> inside the <p> do that?

Comment: Not exactly. The text starts at the baseline of the icon, instead of top-aligned. This is what it looks like in JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5h3ko0a8/

Comment: The text gets under the icon which I do not want.

Comment: Fair enough. If you add a `float: left;` to the `<i>`, then it seems to work: https://jsfiddle.net/w8m64x3b/1/ Also, a slight `margin-right: 2px;` to add some spacing, etc.

Comment: It doesn't ... Resize the window to a smaller size and you will see text going under the icon

Comment: At 142px width, yeah, it goes under... Above that, it looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
i {
  font-size: 36px!important;
  position:relative;
  width:35px;
}

p {
  display: inline-block;
  width:85%;
}

div {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">
      
<div>
  <i class="material-icons">check_circle_outline</i>
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam nec fermentum urna, at convallis turpis. Aliquam luctus mauris arcu, eu sodales mauris sagittis at.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't use 85% because I need the text to fill all width after the Icon. And I also need both icon and text to be top aligned (I think this can be done using vertical-align)

Comment: This is the right approach for that but instead of width:85%; use width: calc(100% - 39px);  This will make it responsively fill the remaining space.  Note: the 4 extra pixels are there because in some browsers inline-blocks have a 1px margin; so, you need to buffer for 1px on either side of both inline-blocks

Answer (score 0):

Try his

CSS

```
.table{
 display: table;
width: 100%;
}
.tablecellleft{
 display: table-cell;
 width: 10px;
}
.tablecellright{
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: top;
}
```

HTML

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">

 <div class="table">
 <div class="tablecellleft">
<i class="material-icons icon">check_circle_outline</i>
 </div>
 <div class="tablecellright">
  ..... here is the text..... here is the text..... here is the text..... here is the text..... here is the text..... here is the text..... here is the text..... here is the text..... here is the text..... here is the text..... here is the text
 </div>
</div>
```